# Undefined property: App\Http\Controllers\PageController::$validate in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have controller with the action

```
public function postContact(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request, [
        'name'    => 'required',
        'email'   => 'required | email',
        'content' => 'required'
    ]);
    if(empty($this->validate->fails())){
        die('wrong');
         return redirect()->route('contact')->withInput();
   }
   return ('right');

}
```

When I don't fill in all input this dies on the wrong statement, but when I fill in all the input this error occurs:

> ErrorException in PageController.php line 123:
>   Undefined property: `App\Http\Controllers\PageController::$validate`

How can I fix this?
Thank for reading my answer:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOHDt.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
if (empty($this->validate()->fails())) {
```

Because `validate()` is a method, not property.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic

Comment: Thank you for this docs. I rewrite (delete if condition ) and it wok

Comment: Why answer when you know that this is simple typo error? There is flag explicitly for this.